# Is there any browser utility I can use in SSH for Linux

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, unix-shell

Is there a text-based browser available for Linux (CentsOS) which I can use when I SSH to my server. 
I use CentOS release 5.5. My server do not have graphic interface.

It would be nice if it support JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Elinks](http://www.elinks.cz/) which originates from links. It has support for Javascript, tabs, frames, tables...

I also like [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/), but I don't think it supports Javascript.

Answer (score 6):

You can try

`links http://www.example.com` or `lynx http://www.example.com`

You can also try `links -g` to put it into "graphics" mode but I don't think this will work over SSH.

Comment: Wow! It's wonderful. But I have small problem. I only can go into href links. I cannot submit form or press <input type="submit" buttons. Is there a way to press buttons or submit forms?

Comment: Note that both of these are available in the CentOS base repo, so you just need to `yum install` them.

Answer (score 3):

If you install a X server such as Cygwin/X on your local machine then you can instruct your SSH client to enable X forwarding and run a graphical browser such as Firefox or Chrome if the `xorg-x11-xauth` package is installed on the server.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is Wikipedia's list of text-based browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#Text-based)

Answer (score 0):

I find it convenient to set up socks forwarding using OpenSSH's `-D $port` option. Then use a firefox extension that does fine-grained proxy configuration (FoxyProxy IIRC), and tell it to tunnel some sites through the socks proxy at `localhost:$port` .

Comment: I already do this using Putty Tunelling. But this is not exactly what I need. I actually want to surf web from inside the server not by tunneling. For example when I want to download file in the server (which I cannot download using wget command).